# If current page URL equals X OR X?

Tags: php, wildcard

I found this code on the internetz, it checks the current page url;

```
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
return $pageURL;
}
```

So now I can do something like this;

```
elseif (curPageURL() == "http://www.example.com/pageexample") {
<meta tags here>
}
```

Great. But I would also like to use this for pagination pages. Those URLs look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=30&groep=0
http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=60&groep=0
http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=90&groep=0
[....]
http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=270&groep=0
```

I could use a if statement for every of those links.. but I would much rather like to use one. Is it possible to add a wildcard or something? Like this I guess (notice the `*`)

```
elseif (curPageURL() == "http://www.example.com/pageexample" OR curPageURL() == "http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=*&groep=0") {
```

**edit**: I would like to do this for all those URLs because I want to give them the same `meta description`, `<title>` and `<link rel="canonical"`. I could do this manually by doing an if-statement for every page (10+ atm) but I figured there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds a lot like regex problem:

```
if (preg_match("#^http://www.example.com/pageexample(\?start=[^&]*&groep=0)?#", curPageURL())) {
    // it matches
}
```

The expression `[^&]*` acts like your `*`.`; to match non-empty items, use`[^&]+`. It matches these:

```
http://www.example.com/pageexample
http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=30&groep=0
```

**Update**

It's not entirely clear why you need to compare against the full canonical URL, unless you have multiple domains point to the same code base.

Comment: I dont think he want http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=&groep=0 as option :/

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses well, it's not entirely clear what he means by `*` or why he wants to compare against the full url in the first place.

Comment: @Linkjuice57 then my answer should work for you, unless you think otherwise, let me know!

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I wanted to do. You did forget one closing bracket :).

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function?  From the manual page:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));

?>

// The above would print
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

For your particular case, you could then just check against the `host` and `path` variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a string comparison function

```
if (strstr(curPageURL(), 'http://www.example.com/')) !== FALSE) {
  // curPageURL() contains http://www.example.com/
}
```

or

```
if (preg_match('/^http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\//', curPageURL()) { 
  // curPageURL() starts with http://www.example.com/
}
```

There's lots of ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap this

```
elseif (curPageURL() == "http://www.example.com/pageexample" OR curPageURL() == "http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=*&groep=0") {
```

in a while loop that adds 30 to a variable where you have your wild card on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

did you try regex?

```
if (preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/pageexample\?start=[0-9]+&groep\=0/i', "http://www.example.com/pageexample?start=34&groep=0")) {
   echo "A match was found.";
else {
   echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: "PHP is the web scripting language of choice."... Copy and paste from [http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)? :)

Comment: @JohnLawrence yes I always forget the Preg_match function so thats why :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the query_string element from the $_SERVER array all your paginated URLs will return the same URL: http://www.example.com/pageexample, you can check with

```
echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ;
```

vs

```
echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'?'.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ;
```

You'll see that in the first case you don't receive GET parameters